# Quais caracteres posso usar para definir o nome de uma classe?

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web

Sei que é recomendado utilizar letras e o traço, porém e se eu quiser usar uma classe `teste1/10`, qual a recomendação?

Comment: classe em css ?

Comment: O ideal é você manter um padrão. Por exemplo, hj é muito comum a nomenclatura com letras, numeros, traços e underline. Eu não recomendo você utilizar outros caracteres para evitar problemas de sintaxe quando tiver que selecionar a classe via javascript ou jQuery.

Comment: Sim LocaHost, mas alan eu posso fazer como falei?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a [Gramática do CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html) do CSS você não pode usar `teste1/10`.

Um nome devem iniciar com letras (`a-z`) ou um hífen (`-`) ou sublinhado (`_`),  ou uma letra (`a-z`), seguido por qualquer número, sublinhados, letras ou números.

Você pode usar `teste110` ou `teste1-10` ou `teste1_10` no seu caso.

Baseada nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/5327226) do stackoverflow inglês.